# How to optimise amount of API calls/DB requests with react-query?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

Our app has a main view which consists of various entities which are fetched from the backend. We went with a rather atomic approach where each entity has its own query handler using react-query. This works very well in itself, but I see a potential drawback with the amount of separate API requests.

Each request will create a DB connection (we use postgres). This is not a problem yet, but with a growing number of entities+queries+users, this will in theory be a problem.

Is there a best practice/pattern for handling this kind of situation? We have an endpoint that loads all the entities with a single call and then populate the cache of atomic queries on initial load.

```
const useFlowInitialLoad = async (id: string) => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient()

  const fetcher = async (): Promise<LoadFlowResponse> => {
    const { data } = await axios.get<LoadFlowResponse>(`${BE_URL}/flows/${id}/load`, {
      withCredentials: true,
    })
    return data
  }

  const data = await fetcher()
  queryClient.setQueryData(['flowLoad', id], data)
  queryClient.setQueryData(['nodes', id], data.flow.nodes)
  queryClient.setQueryData(['links', id], data.flow.links)
  queryClient.setQueryData(['infoNodes', id], data.infoNodes)
  queryClient.setQueryData(['flow', id], data.flow)
  queryClient.setQueryData(['flowValidations', id], data.validation)
  queryClient.setQueryData(['editors', id], data.users)

  return { data }
}
```

This works somewhat fine, but it becomes rather complex when handling refetch on window focus etc.
Is there generally a good pattern for solving this kind of situation?

Comment: Do you need all this data in the main view? If yes, then I think your solution seems fine. If not, then why load them all at once immediately?

Comment: Yes, all that data is needed. The current solution works fine, but is rather hard to manage and scale. We also need to disable refetch on window focus.
I hoped it would be a more common problem and maybe some pattern emerged for this.

Answer (score 0):

Will using the `select` option from `useQuery` instead of `setQueryData` work?

I haven't used it to split a single endpoint like that, though seems like it could be useful.

https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/reference/useQuery